# third party app store

Tags: app-store

i am asked about custom app stores a lot by clients. Is it feasible to maintain a custom appstore for a specific enterprise where all the mobile device apps are available ? and can be deployed OTA ? any framework ? does afaria do that ?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about iPhone apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about apple products, their license strictly forbids that.  you can install android apps from any link on the web and there are many alternate appstores for droid devices. you could write a simple droid app that downloads install files.  blackberry also does not need central approval from RIM to publish and download an app.

Comment: How about windows apps?

Comment: yes you can do it in windows http://blogs.telerik.com/mehfuz-hossain/posts/13-04-16/private-enterprise-app-deployment-for-windows-8